# UIViewController! Does not conform to protocol "LogicValue"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, swift

I am trying to convert the following objective-c code to swift:

```
- (UIViewController *)currentViewController
{
    UIViewController *viewController = self.rootViewController;
    while (viewController.presentedViewController) {
        viewController = viewController.presentedViewController;
    }
    return viewController;
}

#ifdef __IPHONE_7_0

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForStatusBarStyle
{
    UIViewController *currentViewController = [self currentViewController];

    while ([currentViewController childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle]) {
        currentViewController = [currentViewController childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle];
    }
    return currentViewController;
}

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForStatusBarHidden
{
    UIViewController *currentViewController = [self currentViewController];

    while ([currentViewController childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden]) {
        currentViewController = [currentViewController childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden];
    }
    return currentViewController;
}

#endif   

//SWIFT

func currentViewController() -> UIViewController {

    var viewController = self.rootViewController

    while (viewController.presentedViewController) {
        viewController = viewController.presentedViewController
    }
    return viewController

}

func viewControllerForStatusBarStyle() -> UIViewController {

    var cViewController = currentViewController()

    while (cViewController.childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle) {
        cViewController = cViewController.childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle
    }
    return cViewController


}

func viewControllerForStatusBarHidden() -> UIViewController {

   var cViewController = currentViewController()

        while (cViewController.childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden) {
            cViewController = cVC.childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden
        }

        return cViewController

}
```

But I get some errors saying that UIViewController! Does not conform to protocol "LogicValue" at the following line " while (cViewController.childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle)"

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I think more Swift-ish way would be with `while let` syntax: `while let vc = cViewController.childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden() { cViewController = vc }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle()` is a method not a property

```
   while (cViewController.childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle()) {
        cViewController = cViewController.childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle()
}
```